# Only Insert if unique(check 2 rows)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am learning SQL and I am in situation where I have to INSERT values into database only if it do not exist already.

My tableview structure is like this:

```
+----------+-----------+-----+-----+
| first_id | second_id | timestamp |
+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I Want to insert only if there is not same `first_id` and `second_id` e.g if in table there is `first_id 1` and `second_id 2` and I am adding it again, I do not want to add it anymore. So if the first_id and second_id rows already have values 1 and 2 then do not add but if `first_id` is 3 and `second_id` is 1 then I would allow the inserting.

This is my query ATM:

```
INSERT INTO  `testtable`.`ids` (`first_id`, `second_id`) VALUES (:first_id, :second_id)
```

And like this I tried with `NOT EXISTS` but it is not working:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT first_id, second_id FROM `testtable`.`ids` WHERE first_id = : first_id AND second_id = : second_id) INSERT INTO  `testtable`.`ids` (`first_id `, `second_id `) VALUES (: first_id, : second_id)
```

The last mentioned query gives me Syntax error but once I even got the integrity violation and it told me to check documentation.

I am executing my queries using PHP `->query("");` function.

I tried to do like `IF NOT EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` but those didn't work. How should I approach to this?

Comment: Can you allow insert if `first_id` is 1 and `second_id` is 1 or 3? Does it have to be 2 for not insert?

Comment: Yes, if those values now are like `first_id` is 2 and `second_id` is 4 then I would allow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple. Declare `first_id` and `second_id` as `composite key`. I would prefer not to make any changes in your PHP Code but make your DB structure versatile so that it doesn't accept any duplicate values how-so-ever you are inserting it.

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
  `first_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `second_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `first_id` (`first_id`,`second_id`)
)
```

Now `first_id` and `second_id` will never accept duplicate values.[image]

^ table contains values (1,2). Now inserting (1,3).

[image]

^the table accepts (1,3). Now inserting (1,2) again.

[image]

the insert statement throws an error. Now the table will never accept duplicate values for the key (first_id,second_id).

**If the table already exists and you're not creating it from scratch**, simply execute:

```
alter table `table_name` add unique key (first_id, second_id);
```

This will prevent the duplicate values henceforth.

Comment: That was the best one :) Thank you. But can you tell me how I can catch this? I do not want to get internal if it happens. Instead of 500 I would like to get 400 or something.

Comment: My pleasure :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this if you are using PHP and MySql:

```
<?php

    //Added database connection code here 

    $first_id = $_POST['first_id '];
    $second_id = $_POST['second_id '];


    $sql = "select * from ids where first_id = ".$first_id ." and second_id  ='".$second_id."'" ;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    if($row[0]) {
        $mysqli->close();
    } else {
        //preapare an insert statement
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(" INSERT INTO `ids` (first_id, second_id) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $first_id, $second_id);

            //execute the statement
            if( $stmt->execute() ) {
                unset($first_id);
                unset($second_id);
            } else {
                echo $mysqli->error;
            }       
        //close statement
        $stmt->close();     
        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for existence for the first and second ids and additionally declare 2 sql variables for first and second ids and set them as per required.

```
DECLARE @Exists int; @first_id int; @second_id int;
SET @first_id = 1;
SET @second_id = 2;
SELECT @Exists = COUNT(*) FROM [testtable] where [first_id] = @first_id and [second_id] = @second_id;
```

Condition to insert if count of matched records is 0:

```
IF(@Exists = 0)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO  [testtable](first_id, second_id)
    VALUES(@first_id,@second_id)
END
```

Comment: I might sound stupid now but if I am using PHP `->query("")`  function to execute queries, then how I should add it?

Comment: I am not certain how to do achieve this in php, i am a .net professional myself. Sorry.